# Programming a step function

Tags: conditionals

I have, say 7 values ordered increasily, `a_0,a_1,...,a_6`. I want to program a step-function on the intervals of extremity `a_i`, so a function f such that,

```
f(x)=f_0 on [a_0,a_1[, f_1 on [a_1,a_2[..., f_5 on [a_5,a_6[
```

The program for my case gives the values of f for each real value. What is the simplest method to do that on latex ?.. I think that it's a simple program and something like the `\multido` loop does the job, using the `ifthen` package for example, but I'm not familiar with programming in LaTeX.. I don't know how I declare sequences of variables and assign values to this variables.

Ideally for me, will be obtaining a macro `\Step{\alpha,a_i,a_{i+1}}`, which gives `f_{i}` when the condition

```
  {a_i\leq\alpha<a_{i+1}}
```

is true, for several values of `\alpha...` Thank you

Comment: Sorry, your question is totally unclear to me. Do you want to use `LaTeX` to decide what it should print applying this `\Step` function? Shall this macro produce other `LaTeX` code or just output numbers?

Comment: Do you mean some sort of forEach?

Comment: What's the relation between x and alpha?

Comment: sorry because my net was down... I want thatthis macro output the number... and some other calculations.. I use it for computing percentiles (the cumulative frequencies are increasing !)

Comment: @cfr x or alpha is the rank of the percentile... (the value associated to alpha%)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definestepfunction}{mmm}
 { % #1 is the function's name
   % #2 is the semicolon separated subdivision
   % #3 is the semicolon separated list of values
  \faouzi_step_define:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \faouzi_step_define:nnn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_faouzi_step_values_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l_faouzi_step_division_seq - 1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
     {
      \exp_not:N \faouzi_step_compare:nnnn { ########1 }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ##1 } }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ##1 + 1 } }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_values_seq { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  \cs_new:cV { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :n } \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
  \cs_new_eq:Nc { #1 } { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :n }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_new:cn { cV }

\cs_new:Nn \faouzi_step_compare:nnnn
 {
  \fp_compare:nT { #2 <= #1 < #3 } { #4 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definestepfunction{\test}{0;1;2;3}{a;b;c}

\begin{document}

Should be a: \test{0}\par
Should be a: \test{0.2}\par
Should be b: \test{1}\par
Should be b: \test{1.99999}\par
Should be c: \test{2}\par
Should be c: \test{2.3}\par

\end{document}
```

The macro `\test` is built so that it performs a comparison on its argument, delivering the value if the argument fits one of the subintervals.

Nothing is returned if the argument is not in the domain. Error checking could be added for this case.

Note that the values can be arbitrary tokens.

[image]

A version with error checking:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definestepfunction}{mmm}
 { % #1 is the function's name
   % #2 is the semicolon separated subdivision
   % #3 is the semicolon separated list of values
  \faouzi_step_define:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \faouzi_step_define:nnn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_faouzi_step_values_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l_faouzi_step_division_seq - 1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
     {
      \exp_not:N \faouzi_step_compare:nnnn { ########1 }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ##1 } }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ##1 + 1 } }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_values_seq { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  \cs_new:cV { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _aux:n } \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
  \cs_new:cx { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :n }
   {
    \exp_not:N \faouzi_step_check:nnnn
     { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
     { ##1 }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { 1 } }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { -1 } }
   }
  \cs_new_eq:Nc { #1 } { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :n }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_new:cn { cV }

\cs_new:Nn \faouzi_step_compare:nnnn
 {
  \fp_compare:nT { #2 <= #1 < #3 } { #4 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \faouzi_step_check:nnnn
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #3 <= #2 < #4 }
   {
    \use:c { faouzi_step_#1_aux:n } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \msg_error:nnnnn { faouzi/step } { out-of-bounds } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { faouzi/step } { out-of-bounds }
 {% error message
  Value~#1~out~of~bounds~[#2,#3)
 }
 {% help message
  The~given~value~'#1'~is~out~of~bounds,~the~function~
  is~defined~in~the~interval~[#2,#3)
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definestepfunction{\test}{0;1;2;3}{a;b;c}

\begin{document}

Should be a: \test{0}\par
Should be a: \test{0.2}\par
Should be b: \test{1}\par
Should be b: \test{1.99999}\par
Should be c: \test{2}\par
Should be c: \test{2.3}\par
Gives error: \test{-1}\par
Gives error: \test{3}\par
Gives error: \test{3.1}\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: The program you wrote does exactly what I want but I don't understand your program because I don't know the xparse package... I hope that there's not interferences with other packages I use... a good hazard is that I was reading the doc of latex3 project, which is the father of xparse... Thanks

Comment: Other thing. You say "Error checking could be added for this case". Can you add this code because it's real error: the numbers a0,a1,a2 are cumulative frequencies, with maximum 1, and alpha the rank of the percentile, with maximum 100%, so alpha must be in the domain... (in the finite case of course, which is our case!)

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Added.

Comment: Another refinement can be when the output of \definestepfunction{} depends on alpha, the argument of test(alpha)... something like "The percentile P_{alpha} is in the interval (a_i,a_{i+1})", where (a_i,a_{i+1}) is the interval where the test is true.. Any idea about this ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna This is a complete new question, I believe.

Comment: do you think that I must open another question about this ?

Comment: would you see the question opened here, please: 
       http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288733/programming-a-step-function-part2