# Programming a step function- part2

Tags: conditionals, xparse, pgfmath, pgffor

Based on a macro given by egreg in this question:
[Programming a step function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284762/programming-a-step-function/284770?noredirect=1#comment687307_284770)

I obtain a program which tests in which interval is a number \alpha, between the numbers bone, btwo, bthree, bfour. I use this macro to compute the percentiles of statistical data in a simple case.
I wrote this program:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definestepfunction}{mmm}
 { % #1 is the function's name
   % #2 is the semicolon separated subdivision
   % #3 is the semicolon separated list of values
  \faouzi_step_define:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \faouzi_step_define:nnn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_faouzi_step_values_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l_faouzi_step_division_seq - 1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
     {
      \exp_not:N \faouzi_step_compare:nnnn { ########1 }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ##1 } }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ##1 + 1 } }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_values_seq { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  \cs_new:cV { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :n } \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
  \cs_new_eq:Nc { #1 } { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :n }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_new:cn { cV }

\cs_new:Nn \faouzi_step_compare:nnnn
 {
  \fp_compare:nT { #2 <= #1 < #3 } { #4 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{fp}
%%% Bounds of intervals
\FPeval\bone{0}\FPeval\btwo{1}\FPeval\bthree{2}\FPeval\bfour{3}
%%% Example of number
\FPeval\alpha{1.7}

\definestepfunction{\test}{\bone;\btwo;\bthree;\bfour}{
$\bone \leq \alpha < \btwo \Rightarrow \alpha \in [\bone,\btwo[$
;
$\btwo \leq \alpha < \bthree \Rightarrow \alpha \in [\btwo,\bthree[$
;
$\bthree \leq \alpha < \bfour \Rightarrow \alpha \in [\bthree,\bfour[$
}

\begin{document}
\test{\alpha}
\end{document}
```

which gives in the output (depending on \alpha) the good expression:
[image]

But now, because the output depends on \alpha, for another value of \alpha, I must write one stepfunction for each value. This gives this program, for two values \alphaone and \alphatwo, two tests, testone and testtwo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definestepfunction}{mmm}
 { % #1 is the function's name
   % #2 is the semicolon separated subdivision
   % #3 is the semicolon separated list of values
  \faouzi_step_define:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \faouzi_step_define:nnn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_faouzi_step_values_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l_faouzi_step_division_seq - 1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
     {
      \exp_not:N \faouzi_step_compare:nnnn { ########1 }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ##1 } }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ##1 + 1 } }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_values_seq { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  \cs_new:cV { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :n } \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
  \cs_new_eq:Nc { #1 } { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :n }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_new:cn { cV }

\cs_new:Nn \faouzi_step_compare:nnnn
 {
  \fp_compare:nT { #2 <= #1 < #3 } { #4 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{fp}
%%% Bounds of intervals
\FPeval\bone{0}\FPeval\btwo{1}\FPeval\bthree{2}\FPeval\bfour{3}
%%% Example of number
\FPeval\alphaone{1.7}\FPeval\alphatwo{2.3}

\definestepfunction{\testone}{\bone;\btwo;\bthree;\bfour}{
$\bone \leq \alphaone < \btwo \Rightarrow \alphaone \in [\bone,\btwo[$
;
$\btwo \leq \alphaone < \bthree \Rightarrow \alphaone \in [\btwo,\bthree[$
;
$\bthree \leq \alphaone < \bfour \Rightarrow \alphaone \in [\bthree,\bfour[$
}

\definestepfunction{\testtwo}{\bone;\btwo;\bthree;\bfour}{
$\bone \leq \alphatwo < \btwo \Rightarrow \alphatwo \in [\bone,\btwo[$
;
$\btwo \leq \alphatwo < \bthree \Rightarrow \alphatwo \in [\btwo,\bthree[$
;
$\bthree \leq \alphatwo < \bfour \Rightarrow \alphatwo \in [\bthree,\bfour[$
}
\begin{document}
\testone{\alphaone}

\testtwo{\alphatwo}

\end{document}
```

which gives the good output:

[image]

Now, it's clear that I don't want to write one output for each value for my test. So the question is: how can I obtain a macro, which gives the good result for each value of \alpha, so a stepfunction \test which gives the same output for each \alpha, where the command \test(\alpha) gives some thing like:

```
$a\leq \alpha < b \Rightarrow \alpha \in [a,b[$
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier (albeit slower) using pgfmath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up suitably the third argument of `\definetestfunction`, where you can use `#1` to refer to the argument passed to `\test` (or whatever name you choose for the function).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definestepfunction}{mmm}
 { % #1 is the function's name
   % #2 is the semicolon separated subdivision
   % #3 is the semicolon separated list of values
  \faouzi_step_define:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \faouzi_step_define:nnn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_faouzi_step_values_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l_faouzi_step_division_seq - 1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
     {
      \exp_not:N \faouzi_step_compare:nnnn { ########1 }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ##1 } }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ##1 + 1 } }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_values_seq { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  \cs_new:cV { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _aux:n } \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
  \cs_new:cx { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :n }
   {
    \exp_not:N \faouzi_step_check:nnnn
     { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
     { ##1 }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { 1 } }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { -1 } }
   }
  \cs_new_eq:Nc { #1 } { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :n }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_new:cn { cV }

\cs_new:Nn \faouzi_step_compare:nnnn
 {
  \fp_compare:nT { #2 <= #1 < #3 } { #4 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \faouzi_step_check:nnnn
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #3 <= #2 < #4 }
   {
    \use:c { faouzi_step_#1_aux:n } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \msg_error:nnnnn { faouzi/step } { out-of-bounds } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { faouzi/step } { out-of-bounds }
 {% error message
  Value~#1~out~of~bounds~[#2,#3)
 }
 {% help message
  The~given~value~'#1'~is~out~of~bounds,~the~function~
  is~defined~in~the~interval~[#2,#3)
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definestepfunction{\test}{0;1;2;3}
 {
  0\le #1<1 \Rightarrow #1\in[0,1);
  1\le #1<2 \Rightarrow #1\in[1,2);
  2\le #1<3 \Rightarrow #1\in[2,3);
 }

\newcommand{\alphaone}{1.7}
\newcommand{\alphatwo}{2.3}

\begin{document}

$\test{\alphaone}$

$\test{\alphatwo}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I recommend not using `fp` and, above all, not redefining `\alpha`.

### Improved version

In this version, the commands `\LOWER` and `\UPPER` are available in the body of the definition, representing the lower and upper bound of the matching interval. Moreover, if the body of the definition only has one item, this is repeated for all intervals.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpeval}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\definestepfunction}{mmm}
 { % #1 is the function's name
   % #2 is the semicolon separated subdivision
   % #3 is the semicolon separated list of values
   \faouzi_step_define:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\LOWER}{}
 {
  \tl_use:N \l_faouzi_step_lower_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\UPPER}{}
 {
  \tl_use:N \l_faouzi_step_upper_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \l_faouzi_step_lower_tl
\tl_new:N \l_faouzi_step_upper_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \faouzi_step_define:nnn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_faouzi_step_values_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l_faouzi_step_values_seq == 1 }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { \seq_count:N \l_faouzi_step_division_seq - 2 }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_faouzi_step_values_seq { #3 }
     }
   }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l_faouzi_step_division_seq - 1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
     {
      \exp_not:N \faouzi_step_compare:nnnn { ########1 }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ##1 } }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { ##1 + 1 } }
       { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_values_seq { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  \cs_new:cV { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _aux:n } \l_faouzi_step_temp_tl
  \cs_new:cx { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :n }
   {
    \exp_not:N \faouzi_step_check:nnnn
     { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
     { ##1 }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { 1 } }
     { \seq_item:Nn \l_faouzi_step_division_seq { -1 } }
   }
  \cs_new_eq:Nc { #1 } { faouzi_step_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :n }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_new:cn { cV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \faouzi_step_compare:nnnn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_faouzi_step_lower_tl { #2 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_faouzi_step_upper_tl { #3 }
  \fp_compare:nT { #2 <= #1 < #3 } { #4 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \faouzi_step_check:nnnn
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #3 <= #2 < #4 }
   {
    \use:c { faouzi_step_#1_aux:n } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \msg_error:nnnnn { faouzi/step } { out-of-bounds } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { faouzi/step } { out-of-bounds }
 {% error message
  Value~#1~out~of~bounds~[#2,#3)
 }
 {% help message
  The~given~value~'#1'~is~out~of~bounds,~the~function~
  is~defined~in~the~interval~[#2,#3)
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\alphaone}{1.7}
\newcommand{\alphatwo}{2.3}
\newcommand{\bzero}{0}
\newcommand{\bone}{1.7}
\newcommand{\btwo}{2.3}
\newcommand{\bthree}{5.6}

\definestepfunction{\testA}{0;1;2;3}
 {
  \LOWER\le #1<\UPPER \Rightarrow #1\in[\LOWER,\UPPER)
 }

\definestepfunction{\testB}{\bzero;\bone;\btwo;\bthree}
 {
  $\LOWER\le#1<\UPPER$ then the mid-interval is
  $\frac{\LOWER+\UPPER}{2}=\fpeval{(\LOWER+\UPPER)/2}$
 }

\definestepfunction{\testC}{\bzero;\bone;\btwo;\bthree}
 {
  #1 is in the first interval;
  #1 is in the second interval;
  #1 is in the third interval
 }

\begin{document}

$\testA{\alphaone}$

$\testA{\alphatwo}$

\testB{1.5}

\testB{1.7}

\testB{2.6}

\testC{1.5}

\testC{1.7}

\testC{2.6}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your improved version is more useful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without using any special package:

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\definestepfunction#1#2#3{%
   \def#1##1{\def\sfv{##1}\dostepfunction#2;;\end#3\endgame}
}
\def\dostepfunction#1;{%
   \ifdim\sfv pt<#1pt \outofrange \fi
   \dostepfunctionA#1;%
}
\def\dostepfunctionA#1;#2;{%   
   \ifx;#2;\outofrange \fi
   \advance\tmpnum by1
   \ifdim\sfv pt<#2pt \def\sfl{#1}\def\sfr{#2}\dostepfunctionB \fi
   \dostepfunctionA#2;%
}
\def\dostepfunctionB#1\end{\fi\dostepfunctionC}
\def\dostepfunctionC#1;#2{%
   \advance\tmpnum by-1
   \ifnum\tmpnum=0 #1\endgame \fi
   \ifx\endgame#2#1\endgame \fi
   \dostepfunctionC#2
}
\def\outofrange#1\endgame{\fi 
   \errmessage{the value \sfv\space is out of the range}%
}
\def\endgame#1\dostepfunctionC#2\endgame{\fi}
%%% the test:
\definestepfunction\test{0;1;2;3}
{
  0\le \sfv<1 \Rightarrow \sfv\in[0,1);
  1\le \sfv<2 \Rightarrow \sfv\in[1,2);
  2\le \sfv<3 \Rightarrow \sfv\in[2,3);
}
$\test{1.2}$\par
$\test{2.3}$\par
$\test{0}$

%OR
\definestepfunction\test{0;1;2;3}
{
  \sfl\le \sfv<\sfr \Rightarrow \sfv\in[\sfl,\sfr);
}
$\test{1.2}$\par
$\test{2.3}$\par
$\test{0}$
\bye
```

Comment: Your solution is useful too... it's for advanced programmers what I'm not. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer given by John Kormylo, and after reading the doc of pgf, I got a more simple solution based on pgfmaths, which is applicable on more general cases.
The following program tests in which interval is a value, for the intervals with bounds are (for example) \bzero=0, \bone=1.7, \btwo=2.3, \bthree=5.6.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % Need the hole package for the command \pgfmathprintnumber
%\usepackage{pgfmath}% part of the tikz package
%\usepackage{pgffor}% part of the tikz package
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=75mm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\bzero}{0}
\newcommand{\bone}{1.7}
\newcommand{\btwo}{2.3}
\newcommand{\bthree}{5.6}
\def\myarray{{\bzero,\bone,\btwo,\bthree}}

\newcommand{\steps}[1]% #1 = unknown real (text)
{\bgroup% local definitions
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {0,...,2} %j:=i+1
    {
        \pgfmathparse{\myarray[\i]}
        \let\minbound=\pgfmathresult 
        \pgfmathparse{\myarray[\j]}
        \let\maxbound=\pgfmathresult 
        \pgfmathparse
            {
                ifthenelse(and(notless(#1,\myarray[\i])==1,less(#1,\myarray[\j])==1),   
                "$\minbound \leq #1 < \maxbound$ then the mid-interval is 
                $\displaystyle\frac{\minbound + \maxbound}{2}=$",
                "")
            }
        \pgfmathresult 
        % An example of some calculus
        \pgfmathparse
            {
                ifthenelse(and(notless(#1,\myarray[\i])==1,less(#1,\myarray[\j])==1),   
                (\minbound+\maxbound)/2, 
                "")
            }
        \pgfmathresult
    }
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\steps{1.5}
\vspace{.5cm}
\\
\steps{1.7}
\vspace{.5cm}
\\
\steps{2.6}
\end{document}
```

The test on the values 1.5, 1.7 et 2.6 gives an example of the suitable output, mixing of literal expression and some numerical computation :
[image]

Comment: Yup, that's how you do it.

Comment: I still have the problem of compilation  of  `\pgfmathprintnumber{\steps{1.5}}`
 even if I load the tikz package

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pgfmath version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}% part of the tikz package

\newcommand{\steps}[1]% #1 = unknown real (text)
{\bgroup% local definitions
 \pgfmathint{#1}% or \pgfmathparse{int(#1)}
 \let\less=\pgfmathresult
 \pgfmathparse{int(ceil(#1))}
 \let\more=\pgfmathresult
 $\less \leq #1 \leq \more \Rightarrow #1 \in [\less,\more]$
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\steps{1.7}

\steps{2.3}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

For this problem is was easier to use a plain TeX `\if` `\else` `\fi` than the `ifthenelse` from `pgfmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % Need the whole package for the command \pgfmathprintnumber
%\usepackage{pgfmath}% part of the tikz package
%\usepackage{pgffor}% part of the tikz package
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=75mm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\myarray{{0,1.7,2.3,5.6}}

\newcommand{\steps}[1]% #1 = unknown real (text)
{\bgroup% local definitions
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {0,...,2} %j:=i+1
    {
        \pgfmathparse{\myarray[\i]}%
        \let\minbound=\pgfmathresult 
        \pgfmathparse{\myarray[\j]}%
        \let\maxbound=\pgfmathresult 
        \pgfmathparse{and(notless(#1,\minbound)==1,less(#1,\maxbound)==1)}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax% actually \if\pgfmathresult 1 would have been faster
          \pgfmathparse{(\minbound+\maxbound)/2}%
          $\minbound \leq #1 < \maxbound$ then the mid-interval is 
            $\displaystyle\frac{\minbound + \maxbound}{2}=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$
        \fi
    }
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\steps{1.5}
\vspace{.5cm}
\\
\steps{1.7}
\vspace{.5cm}
\\
\steps{2.6}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, which seems so simple, but there is a problem. I see that it takes the integer part of the argument #1 (`\pgmathint` and others) but my step functions have more general bounds, not only integers... I gave the numbers 0;1;2;3 only for simplification

Comment: More explicitly, if I have an increasing list of numbers a1,a2,a3, how can I test simply in which interval is a number, using pgfmaths... I'll read the doc for some idea, but your help is wellcome

Comment: You can create an array, use a foreach loop and ifthenelse logic.

Comment: would you see my answer

Comment: I have still another (small) problem. How can I display the numbers in the output, with two digits after period... 0.85 instead of 0.84999 for example. The commands like \pgfmathprintnumber{\steps{1.7}} are not accepted ...

Comment: Evidently, you have to load the whole tikz package for \pgfmathprintnumber.

Comment: `@JohnKormylo` I haven't found a solution to apply the command `\pgfmathprintnumber` to my output.

Comment: I well received your improved version. Thanks